# REST API not working in custom post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I have created the custom post in function.php file, it is working fine for me. When I call custom post data via WordPress REST API, It is showing me the error on browser.

Below is the error which was showing me in the browser.

```
code    "rest_no_route"
message "No route was found matching the URL and request method"
data    
status  404
```

But rest API is working for default post which is present in WordPress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For custom post we need to allow the Rest API below is the code

```
'show_in_rest' => true,
```

Comment: inside the custom post where I need to put this code?

Comment: Add this into the custom post argument.